# How to solve android Overflow issue in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I just got started using react-native and I am seeing an issue with overflow property, from my research I came to know the android by default has overflow: 'hidden', How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: You can try using this workaround module - https://github.com/entria/react-native-view-overflow

Comment: This module results in `Invariant Violation` for me and others.

Answer (score 0):

It is an open bug, not yet resolved. You can nenver have `overflow:'visible'` on android. Only thing it will do is allow stuff outside of the `borderRadius` to show.

Related issues:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6802
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17074

Answer (score 0):

Overflow is supported in react native 0.57.0 and up. Just pass `overflow: visible` to the style props.

Answer (score -3):

i am use absolute and margin property to resovle this issue:
example:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{position:'absolute',top:0,zIndex:10}}></View>
     <View style={{marginTop:25}}></View>
</View>
```

Comment: How come this will fix the overflow issue?